# Can people sue the state lottery for jeopardizing physical or financial safety due to lack of anonymity?

Tags: united-states, lotteries

I had a discussion with a friend and we both ended up agreeing that it recklessly endangers a lottery winner to publicly reveal their identity. If that person becomes robbed, hacked and/or injured soon after winning as a result of being revealed, can't they sue the state government for being so blatantly careless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have the rep for a comment, but a quick google search would reveal there is at least precedence of remaining anonymous in a "Right to Know" law state (is the correct term? I'm not a US citizen, nor have any legal background) in the case of [Jane Doe vs New Hampshire Lottery Commission](http://mediad.publicbroadcasting.net/p/nhpr/files/201803/jane_doe_v._nh_lottery_commission_-_order_3-12-18.pdf)

While this doesn't cover any part of suing the state as mentioned above, it does cover the underlying reason why you would likely be unsuccessful in attempting it, namely the freedom of information that is allowed to citizens of most US states.

Comment: Interesting if true in its extension. I suppose since it is public money then it would make sense for the public to be able to keep track of it, though on the other hand, the federal government also spends money on the federal witness protection program, and doesn't reveal the participants since it is an obvious danger. Not to mention the fact that the IRS doesn't openly disclose everyone's personal finances despite people paying taxes. The case you cite seems to be on the basis of an invasion of privacy though, not bodily harm to a person and/or their family.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted initially anyway? Citing actual precedence is the most proactive thing anyone here has done.

Answer (score 6):

The level of anonymity or privacy given by the lottery administrator (the state) to the lottery winner depends on the terms and conditions of lottery that are accepted as a binding contract when the buyer buys a lottery ticket. It's all in the small print. If you don't like the terms of the lottery, don't buy a ticket.

The lottery terms probably says that the state can use the winner's name in marketing and promotional materials. For a winner to be able to be anonymous, the terms of the lottery would have to specifically state that anonymity is guaranteed, while at the same time, allowing the state to report the winner to the IRS for tax purposes. (Delaware, Kansas, Maryland, North Dakota, Ohio and South Carolina all allow lottery winners to remain anonymous.)

The winner will have little recourse against the state due to circumstances - like being robbed or fleeced - which are outside of the state's control because they are actions by individuals, not the state. The state is also not guilty of "recklessly endangering people" because the ticket buyer knowingly bought a ticket, hoping to win, and agreed to terms.

And it's quite difficult to sue any form of government; states and the federal government are by law immune to most legal actions. The recourse of the ticket buyer - or group of buyers who were possibly harmed as a result of winning - is to encourage the legislation of laws that provide for the anonymity of winners.

Comment: I don't see how conditions are relevant in this case. If you sign a contract to kill someone, you still go to prison. If the state government's decisions are recklessly endangering people when it is 100% avoidable, then that choice of the state to impose that risk is still the state's fault no matter what conditions anyone agrees to. Couldn't at least a class action lawsuit of multiple lottery winners do something?

Comment: The state does not force someone to buy a lottery ticket and enter into a contract regarding the winnings. The state is immune by law. The state is not "recklessly endangering people"; people make a choice when they buy a ticket. Delaware, Kansas, Maryland, North Dakota, Ohio and South Carolina all allow lottery winners to remain anonymous. If a winner is not in one of those states, find a lawyer and sue the state for recklessly endangering people; you'll lose, but that's one way to possibly encourage the state leg. to pass laws like the other states that seek to protect winners.

Comment: @user14554 that's some convoluted thinking going on right there... if the individual doesn't want exposure in the event they win, then they shouldn't buy a ticket, simple enough. The state isn't being reckless, they give people ample opportunity not to buy a ticket.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I see what you're trying to say from a bureaucratic standpoint, but it's also lacking the ever-crucial common sense. Suppose park-goers sign a waiver that no park staff are responsible for injuries. 

Then, for fun, a roller coaster operator intentionally takes a sledge hammer, and while 20 people are riding it, the operator knocks out a steel beam leading 20 people to be injured or killed. Wouldn't you agree that it's simply common sense the operator's actions lead to injuries? Regardless of any contract, it's still the choice of the staff to be a danger to the public.

Comment: @user14554 wilful endangerment is a whole different ballgame, and your example is nothing like a state lottery publicity policy.

Comment: *Willful endangerment* is exactly the point. By willfully forgoing a basic precaution similar to the before mentioned psychopathic operator, such as forgoing anonymity, the state is exposing members of the public to the completely unnecessary risk of physical and financial harm. There is no rational reason to the public's benefit that it shouldn't be anonymous, the conditions seem more like an outdated policy.

Comment: Laws do not appear out of thin air; they must be legislated. The state is not "willfully forgoing a basic precaution such as anonymity" because there is no legal mandate to offer anonymity to lottery winners in those states that do not aleady offer anonymity to winners by law.

Comment: Whether harm is explicit or not is irrelevant, your argument is nothing but semantics. There isn't a specific law that explicitly states I can't randomly shoot someone specifically with a cucumber launcher, but it is still illegal to do so because that specific circumstance is protected by more general laws that enforce private and public safety.

Comment: @user14554 if the state can issue people and vehicles with driver and vehicle licenses without being exposed to endless "reckless endangerment" lawsuits, then lack of anonymity in a voluntary state lottery isn't going to come close.  The gambler should be accepting that responsibility for themselves.

Comment: Did said person *ask* to be shot with a cucumber launcher?

Comment: @Moo The "gamble" is the money tendered for the slim chance of gaining more money, as in a casino, not money for risk of physical harm. To some extent states could be held liable for something mandated, but the DMV case, it is the responsibility of each individual user. In the case of a lottery, It is **not** the choice of a winner whether they can claim a prize and remain anonymous in a state that does not enforce anonymity. The power and therefore responsibility lies exclusively with the state. If a winner chose to forgo anonymity after an option to retain it, only then is it their risk.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch No.

Comment: @user14554 "money tendered for the slim chance of gaining more money" under specific, well publicised conditions.  The gambler takes on the responsibility.  In the case of the DMV, pedestrians are exposed to the risk of drivers and vehicles licensed by the state without any choice.  You seem to be wanting to make an issue out of nothing - you'd have equal chance of saying the state owes a duty of care so that winners don't drink and party themselves into oblivion once the money is handed over.

Comment: @Moo I want to ask about a **known** and **documented** issue that I saw *multiple* people come to the same common-sense conclusion on. The specific laws you imply only prove my point. Participants in Russian Roulette where a member dies are convicted for murder or manslaughter. In a similar way, someone should not have to gamble money for physical harm when such risk by the state is 100% avoidable and the legal precedent for gambling is money for money, not money for harm.

Comment: @user14554 sorry, but I disagree with you - this simply isn't an important issue.  The conditions of the lottery is state well in advance, it's a voluntary act to take part, the state has utterly no case to answer here - they aren't causing harm and they aren't responsible for others causing harm.  The entire risk is 100% avoidable by the individual not buying a ticket.

Comment: @Moo I agree that it's not a widespread issue, but it's also willful harm for any state to try and uphold such a policy as it objectively endangers members of the public in a wholly unnecessary way which does have legal precedence. By your own haphazard reasoning, you've just opened the door to slavery since you must agree it should have been allowed simply because people's freedom wasn't enforced in the past. That's the flaw in bureaucracy, at the end of the day, someone is guilty of enabling the system, So if this policy is worth enforcing, can you cite even any benefits it gives the public?

Comment: @user14554 so we've gone from state lottery to me opening the door to slavery?  I think this conversation is over.

Comment: @Moo It was over the moment you forgot the law exists as a social construct to protect people, not the public bureaucracy itself.

Comment: @user14554 Once you start talking about what the law should be, or purposes for laws, you're off-topic here.  Try politics.stackexchange.com.  You've gotten a good answer on anything on-topic here, and arguing that the answer would be different in an ideal universe, or for that matter in your own idiosyncratic view of the law,  is way off-topic.

Comment: @DavidThornley You're fallaciously assuming that anything before-mentioned is only my personal view when in fact these laws have already been determined by legislators. Don't you agree that throughout the history of known civilization, members of many different societies have agreed to hold members liable for damages to others? Now you're strawmanning because no one here is suggesting to change the law, I brought to light a way to uphold it by not unnecessarily subjecting citizens to danger. The discussion here has nothing to do with changing the law, it's about what falls under its umbrella.